# How can I encapsulate global config settings from different app parts in a single file?

Tags: .net, iis, configuration-files

We have an IIS based application with different web apps, some third party components and several services.

- Server1

  - AppPool1

    - App1
  - AppPool2

    - Third party app
- Server2

  - AppPool3

    - Third party app 2
    - App2
  - Windows Service
  - CLR Stored Proc

The goal is to put all environment relevant settings (such as connection strings, URLS, etc.) into a single configuration file per environment (dev., test, integration, production). The application relevant stuff should be based on this 'global' settings file and individual settings files per application.

I have to use the built-in static `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class because some third party tools depend on it.
I know of the following possible approaches using  `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`:

- Individual files (current, redundant approach)
- Machine.config (too global)
- Hierarchical configuration in IIS (doesn't affect Service and CLR Proc)

**Edit:**
The `linkedConfiguration` element only affects loader binding policies.

Are there other methods?
Which one is best?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you are using a database. You can create a DB in your database server to store configuration values, either shared or per-application. Then, the only thing you need to store in each web.config is a connection string to the "configuration database".

Or, perhaps you can create a Web Service that serves up configuration values in a similar way.

Comment: Of course we have a DB, the CLR stored proc is located in one of the DBs. But I explicitly mentioned the static `ConfigurationManager` class which does not support configs provided by DB or services. I have to use this built in standard because the third party tools depend on it.